# coovachilli + freeradius, how to check how many users are currently login?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, freeradius, coovachilli

I installed CoovaChilli (AC) + freeradius in Ubuntu 10.10 successfully. How could I check how many user has already login and still remain active ?

Comment: Chilli provides a command "chilli_query list", so it can list the current logged in user.

Answer (score -2):

I make possible this with this script or add-on, in his last version v2.0 Final operative functional, make possible say maxim number of guest, only a user for account, mac-ban ip-mac, mac-ip, list of user and connections and more features that your user do not know never. This add-on called Absoloom can be found at
http://bbs.belchi.org/BPI/descarga.php?code=54943

Link´s version change whit time, but you can ever found  the last version of this script in http://bbs.belchi.org into prog-bbs section

I made another release more compact, in the same link full of features

http://bbs.belchi.org/foro/viewtopic.php?f=2

Comment: What features are added? Any further comments? The link might break at any time, and this answer should be able to stand on its own...

Comment: interactive firewall, macban, ipmac,macip,maybe any features includes can not be know for yours user, I´m alone programing this script but you ever can found the last version on my bbs. pendig is the setup come in time. and about the link you ask about RC or the future. The link version will change, but i do not know how